# Prevent content from a div showing under another div

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent this happening. How can I avoid the limits in red are not surpassed by the central text? At full screen the text is shown correctly but when I resize I want the text to stay as a "block".

```
<div class="centered">
  <div style="float: left; width: 20%;text-align : left">Title1      Title2<br>Components<br> Comp1 <br> Comp2 <br> Comp3 <br> Comp4 <br> Comp5 <br> Comp6 </div>
  <div style="width: 80%;text-align : center; float: middle;"><p align="justify"> Historia </p></div></div>
</div>
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: Please include a more complete sample of your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: try the [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html) or set the heights of the divs to the same amount of pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `overflow: hidden` to the second div.

That way it will force it to stay as block element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqU6r/)

Answer (score 2):

The second nested div should have a `float: left;` property, there isn't a `float: middle`

Comment: You are right. Anyway it worked even that way but I fixed it right now.